# Trying to get program to read a file word by word until the EOF, cannot get while( .... != EOF) to work

Tags: c, file, if-statement, while-loop, eof

This is my code, my intention is to use the while loop to run he code until it reads all the words in the Cauchy.txt file. It is reading only some of the words in the file.  Any pointers on what i'm doing wrong?

the data is the Cauchy.txt files is as follows --

```
Baron Augustin-Louis Cauchy was a French mathematician reputed as a pioneer of analysis. He was one of the
first to state and prove theorems of calculus rigorously, rejecting the heuristic principle of the generality
of algebra of earlier authors. He almost singlehandedly founded complex analysis and the study of permutation
groups in abstract algebra. A profound mathematician, Cauchy had a great influence over his contemporaries and
successors. His writings range widely in mathematics and mathematical physics.

More concepts and theorems have been named for Cauchy than for any other mathematician (in elasticity alone
there are sixteen concepts and theorems named for Cauchy). Cauchy was a prolific writer; he wrote approximately
eight hundred research articles and five complete textbooks.
```

I tried

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<errno.h>

int main()
{
    char MyString[30];

    char fname[] = "Cauchy.txt";   // File name for reading data

    FILE* finp;  // File pointer

    // The next line specifies the complete path
    finp = fopen("C:\\CodingC\\exercise 3\\ReadCauchy\\Cauchy.txt", "r");

    int status = fscanf(finp, "%s", &MyString[0]);
    // Read a few words from the input file
    if ((finp = fopen(fname, "r")) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "File %s not found\n", fname);
    }
    else {
        fprintf(stdout, "Reading file %s\n", fname);
        do {
            fscanf(finp, "%s", &MyString[0]);
            fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", MyString);
        }
        while (fscanf(finp, "%s", &MyString[0]) != EOF);
    }

    system("pause");
        return 0;
}
```

This is what the program puts out:

```
Reading file Cauchy.txt
Baron
Cauchy
a
mathematician
as
pioneer
analysis.
was
of
first
state
prove
of
rigorously,
the
principle
the
of
of
authors.
almost
founded
analysis
the
of
groups
abstract
A
mathematician,
had
great
over
contemporaries
successors.
writings
widely
mathematics
mathematical
More
and
have
named
Cauchy
for
other
(in
alone
are
concepts
theorems
for
Cauchy
a
writer;
wrote
eight
research
and
complete
textbooks.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: `while (fscanf(finp, "%s", &MyString[0]) != EOF);` was sit your intent to attach that to a `do` somewhere? Because as written that will consume  every readable char sequence until EOF, doing *nothing* with them. You effectively have a `while` loop whose body is *nothing*.

Comment: Is it your intent to open the file, read once from it without checking if it was actually opened, then open the file again?

Comment: I fixed the file up a little with a do function, now i have part of the Cauchy.txt file printing. Some words are missing, not sure what is occurring now, updating my code right now after this comment. Thanks for helping ! :)

Comment: So, after the edit you're reading a value in the loop and printing it then reading another value in the `while` condition and discarding it. Try `while (fscanf(finp, "%s", MyString) == 1) { fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", MyString); }`

Comment: Okay big edit, I decided to delete fscanf(finp, "%s", &MyString[0]); and left         do {
          
            fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", MyString);
        }
        while (fscanf(finp, "%s", &MyString[0]) != EOF);

Comment: Do you want to open the file `"Cauchy.txt"` or `"C:\\CodingC\\exercise 3\\ReadCauchy\\Cauchy.txt"`? Or do both refer to the same file? In that case, it does not make sense to open the same file twice.

Comment: You're still skipping every other word because you read twice and print once. A do/while loop is the wrong tool for this job because you only want to print when the read was successful. With a do/while you can't check if the read worked until after you've used the incorrect data. I'd advise rewriting this so you open the file once. If the file pointer is NULL handle the error. If not, use the loop from my earlier comment. What it does is read once then print once until a read fails for any reason.

Comment: Hey Ninja and Wenzel, I see what you're saying about opening the file twice, that is actually how my professor suggested opening files. Is there a reason she'd suggest we do it that way? In any case, I got the print to work with the solution update below

Answer (score 0):

This ended up working

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<errno.h>

int main()
{
char MyString[30] = { 0 };

char fname[] = "Cauchy.txt";   // File name for reading data

FILE* finp;  // File pointer



// The next line specifies the complete path
finp = fopen("C:\\CodingC\\exercise 3\\ReadCauchy\\Cauchy.txt", "r");


// Read a few words from the input file
if ((finp = fopen(fname, "r")) == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "File %s not found\n", fname);
}
else {
    fprintf(stdout, "Reading file %s\n", fname);
    do {
        
        fprintf(stdout, "%s\  ", MyString);
    }
    while (fscanf(finp, "%s", MyString) != EOF);
}

system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Best practices: call [`fclose`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fclose) on a `FILE *` when you are done with it.

Comment: Although this attempt is better, it still prints an unnecessary empty string at the beginning. Like Retired Ninja said above, the `do`/`while` loop is not the right tool here. But, in any case, opening the file twice is completely redundant.

Comment: For some reason when I run the file in visual studio, it does not actually print anything extra in the beginning (that I can notice?),  and the opening file twice I get , I am going to mess around and see if I can remove it without crashing the file

Comment: `do { fprintf(stdout, "%s\  ", MyString); } while (fscanf(finp, "%s", MyString) != EOF);` --> `while (fscanf(finp, "%29s", MyString) == 1) { fprintf(stdout, "%s ", MyString); }`.  Limit input test first against success not one kind of failure.